# Can k8s work with an even number of master nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I know it is recommended to have an odd number of master nodes. But will k8s work if we have an even number of nodes? And what are the downsides?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm building an IoT cluster, where every node is a master node. All devices are the same and any device must be able to take up the master role if the current master fails.
Also the number of devices could be any, so the system should work with both odd or even numbers of nodes.

Comment: iirc, you can have even numbers of control plane nodes but you don't get any additional resilience compared to the odd number below it e.g. a 4 node cluster is no more resilient than 3, but 5 would be.

Comment: Although if your IoT nodes are not geographically close, the performance is likely to be terrible so you could instead just have 3 master nodes and then make all of the IoT devices user nodes instead.

Comment: the nodes will be in the same LAN. close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/high-availability-host-numbers/13143/2 says that you should avoid ever having more than 7 master nodes due to the overhead of membership algorithms so depending on how many IoT nodes you have, you should consider a different architecture.

Nodes are supposed to be abstracted away from their purpose so you shouldn't need your user nodes to be the system nodes and this might introduce tightly coupled problems later on.